# Server refused our key (AWS) - Putty

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, putty

I've just signed up to AWS and launched EC2, downloaded key (`.pem`) file then generated ppk file using `puttykeygen`. Using this `ppk` file I've tried to log in to the server via SSH using Putty but it's giving me `Server refused our key` error with pop up:

```
Disconnected: No support authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

I've also used both `ec2-user` and `root` but both don't seem to work with same error.

I'm using Amazon Linux AMI so [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html) page recommends using `ec2-user` which I am already using.
I've also followed the instructions on that page step by step but getting the same error above.

I've also Googled around but couldn't come to the resolution. Is this a bug in Putty or am I missing something?

Comment: I've already tried that one and that didn't work so it's not a duplicate

Comment: double check the instance you installed & double check the format of your key file.  maybe contact amazon support through their forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=371632

Comment: Found out PuttyGen generates Public Key that is different from what is supplied from AWS under authorized_keys. I had to load private key then copy paste Public Key supplied in PuttyGen then add this to authorized_keys on AWS server after logging in via browser using Java. When I used the matching generated ppk file it worked instantly after that

Comment: Can you post the solution (in above comments) to the answer section below and accept it? It'll be useful to future reader because [comment has less visibility than answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931) and this question won't floating in un-answered pool

Comment: @masegaloeh I just did. Tx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out PuttyGen generates Public Key that is different from what is supplied from AWS under `authorized_keys`. I had to load private key then copy paste Public Key supplied in PuttyGen then add this to `authorized_keys` on AWS server after logging in via browser using Java. When I used the matching generated `ppk` file it worked instantly after that