# Connecting AWS from Windows. Error: Using username "ec2-user". Server refused our key

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, putty, aws-cli

I am connecting AWS EC2 using Putty from Windows 8, I followed all steps mentioned on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html) of conversion of .pem to .ppk and have loaded .ppk in Putty.

**Putty Configurations:**

1. Host Address: ec2-user@PUBLIC_DNS_ADDRESS
2. Connection Type: SSH
3. Private key file is set in Connection -> SSH -> Auth

Now when I click Open, it shows error.

> **Using username "ec2-user". Server refused our key**

Note: Also tried root user

Please have a look at below screen.

[image: error screen]

**Security Groups** -> MY Group -> Edit Inbound Rules

As you can see connection is allowed form everywhere.

[image: SSH rule in AWS Inbound Rules]

Comment: Try getting more information by using the -v option for putty, or trying the ssh command with -v

Comment: Also, see the answer to this extremely similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/626825/server-refused-our-key-aws-putty?rq=1

Comment: why down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Change your username to "root" and it can work or AWS will tell you what username you should use.

Comment: I already tried root

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614254/server-refused-our-key-after-launching-instance-from-private-ebs-ami

Comment: I suggest to elaborate more your answer.

Comment: its already pretty much explained, can you please tell me what is unclear?